# setTimeout test does not run as expected

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, settimeout, jasmine

I am new to Jasmine and I have a problem with the following test:

```
describe("my test suite", function() {
    it("my testcase", function() {
        var callbackWasCalled = false;
        function callback(){
            callbackWasCalled = true;
        }
        methodToTest(callback);
        expect(callbackWasCalled).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

In most cases that works but this code does not:

```
methodToTest(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() { callback(); }, 100);
}
```

Why is that?
When I add a console.log in the callback I see that it gets called.

Comment: `setTimeout` does not pause the script. It runs the callback asynchronously, so `expect()` is not blocked, and is therefore invoked long before the `callback` is invoked.

Comment: If you add some more `console.log()` statements before and after calling `methodToTest()` then you can see the full sequence in which the code is executed. Note that `setTimeout(callback, 100);` would do the same thing as `setTimeout(function() { callback(); }, 100);` - you don't need the anonymous function unless you have other statements to include in it (or if you want to use `.call()` or `.apply()` on `callback()`).

Comment: Thanks for your replies. @user1689607: You are right. A second console.log after the expect showed that it was called first. @ nnnnnn: That's true but of course my real world case is not that simple ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason is that the test has completed before the callback was called. Try jasmine.Clock to mock the settimeout method.

Comment: I have googled the jasmine.Clock and it looks like the solution for my dilemma. It seems that jasmine has far more possibilities than I thought. Thanks for that hint.